# How do one prove fourth moment of student t-distribution with df = 4 is infinite?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm currently making some statistics on financial return data. It shows it has very heavy tails and a student t-distribution with 4 degree of freedom fits nicely. This is due to the infinite fourth moment of this distribution. But how can one prove this?

Edit: I've fitted my data with a GARCH(1,1)-process. This is the standardized residuals. How should I interpret my [image: QQ-plot?]

The QQ-plot is the residuals from my fitted model against the quantiles of a t-distribution with four degree of freedom.

Comment: Interesting that you found $\nu=4$. [An alternative parameterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Gaussian_distribution#Student's_t-distribution) used in finance [empirically suggested](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0204331.pdf) $q=1.5\implies\nu=3,\,\beta=\frac23$.

Comment: I didn't actually find this, I'm "playing" around with different assumptions. But could you help me out interpretting my plots I've putted into the question?

Comment: I could try, if you edit in a completion of "How should I interpret my".

Comment: Yeah, I meant the QQ-plot. This is the "most beautiful" fit I got between a standard normal, t-distribution with three degrees of freedom and t-distribution with four degrees of freedom. But to me it still looks VERY heavy tailed.

Comment: I suggest you let an algorithm estimate $\nu$ for you instead of trying values yourself. [Here](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/quantitative-risk-management-in-r/real-world-returns-are-riskier-than-normal?ex=11) is an example.

Comment: I actually already did that, but I got df = 4.357 and some location and scale parameter. But in my case (since I use GARCH) my distribution of the residuals should have mean 0 and variance 1. The quantiles from a t-distribution with 4.357 degrees of freedom didn't produce a better QQ-plot in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDF of the Student's T distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom
is a positive constant times $(1+t^2/\nu)^{-(\nu+1)/2}$, which as $t \to \infty$ is asymptotic to a positive constant times $t^{-(\nu+1)}$.  Thus
the integrand in $\mathbb E[T^\nu] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty t^\nu f(t)\; dt$ goes to $0$ like $t^{-1}$,
which is not integrable.

Comment: Which doesn't really guarantee that the fit should be good, but it does confirm that the tail behavior agrees.

Comment: Would it suffice to show that if $k_\nu$ is the kurtosis function for a t-distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom then $\lim_{\nu\searrow 4} k_\nu = \lim_{\nu\searrow 4} \frac{6}{\nu-4}=\infty$?

Comment: Now, I've fitted my data, but actually it doesn't seem to me that the residuals are following a t-distribution with four degrees of freedom. Can you help me out?

Comment: I thought the "this" you wanted to prove was that Student's T with $4$ degrees of freedom has infinite fourth moment.